# Why is my code bypassing my else if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, try-catch

newbie in java here, just messing around with my project and noticed that my code output doesnt perform my else if loop. if i input the wrong answer to my quiz (A or C), there is no output and it will skip straight to my try block code.

however if i input the correct answer it will output the right code, its only if i input the wrong answer.

```
  @SuppressWarnings("resource")
                    Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);

                    String answer1 = keyboardInput.nextLine(); 
                    if(answer1.equals("B")) {
                    correctCount++;
                    System.out.println("----Thats the correct answer!----  +");
                    }
                    else if(answer1.equals("A" + "C")) {
                    System.out.println("Wrong answer, sorry");
                }


                    try{
                     doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                     System.out.println("Next Question");
                    NodeList q2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("q2");
```

Thanks for any help! and i'm aware my code may be messy aha

Comment: Why didn't you just use a blank else rather than checking on further conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if(answer1.equals("A" + "C"))` --> This checks if answer1 is equal to "AC". Instead of OR operator which is `||` you concatenated two strings. Try 
   `if(answer1.equals("A") || answer1.equals("C"))`

Comment: Out of topic, try to indent your code so it is readable for you and for others.

Answer (score 0):

`else if(answer1.equals("A" + "C")) {`

means:

`else if(answer1.equals("AC")) {`

"A" + "C" is concatenation of strings, "A" + "C" produces a new String "AC".

Answer (score 0):

Ok so first off you're not checking if the answer is A OR C, you're checking if the answer is 'AC'. To achieve what you need you might use the following code

```
if(answer1.equals("B")) {
     correctCount++;
     System.out.println("----Thats the correct answer!----  +");
} else if(answer1.equals("A") || answer1.equals("C")) {
     System.out.println("Wrong answer, sorry");
}
```

But honestly you wouldn't even need the else if statement, because whatever letter he writes that is not B is not correct. Unless you want to handle the 'non existing answer' too

```
do {
   System.out.println("Please choose A, B or C");
   String answer1 = keyboardInput.nextLine();
} while (!answer1.equals("A") && !answer1.equals("B") && !answer1.equals("C"));

if (answer1.equals("B")) {
   //code...
} else {
   //code...
}
```

This way you won't even have to check if it's A or C because you checked already if it was A B or C, so if it's not B it's going to be either two of the wrong answers